# Call method from another class with broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to call a method from my MainActivity when my broadcastreceiver receives that wifi state has changed. My code in my receiver class looks like this:

```
public class ActionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Wifi toggled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

for the broadcastreceiver (the toast works perfectly fine) and i want to call a method which creates notification which looks like this:

```
public void createNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.nTitle))
            .setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.nText));

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(notiId, builder.build());
}
```

if I just say:

```
MainActivity.createNotification();
```

in the onReceive it wont work. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You could just move all that code to the onReceive method, or make the method static and pass in the context. Either of those should work. But as you have it, `MainActivity.createNotification()` will not work because the method isn't static, but you are trying to invoke it as if it were.

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity is class and what you need is to access the running instance and so you need to use the passed back instance ,context but you need to cast it so you can use the following:

```
((MainActivity) context).createNotification();
```